# A good metric for transversal intersections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ be a transversal set of smooth compact orientable sub-manifolds of a compact orientable manifold $M$, and set $V=\bigcap V_i$.

Is it always possible to equip a neighborhood $U$ of $V$ in $M$ with a metric $g$ such that every $V_i\cap U$ is totally geodesic?

or that the exponential map $exp: N_V^M=TV^{\perp g} \to U$ maps very $(N_V^M \cap TV_i)|_V$ into $V_i$?

If not, what are the obstructions?

Edit (Misha): Just to clarify things: Smooth submanifolds $M_1,...,M_k$ of a smooth manifold $M$ are said to *intersect transversally* at a point $x$ if
$$
codim_{T_x M} \bigcap_{i=1}^k T_x M_i= \sum_{i=1}^k codim_M M_i. 
$$
In other words, codimension of intersection (at the tangent space level) is the sum of codimensions.

Comment: You can always make a closed submanifold totally geodesic for some metric on the ambient manifold.  I don't see why you're bringing in intersections.

Comment: all the $V_i$ at the same time Sir! not just $V$. Read the question carefully before you vote to close it.

Comment: This is an OK question for MO. Even if $k=2$ and $V$ has trivial normal bundle the answer is unclear since the problem is to extend the metric from a neighborhood of the intersection while keeping each $V_i$ totally geodesic. (Partition of unity will not work directly, of course.)

Comment: @MohammadF.Tehrani I think we must be careful to use "transversal". What of the following two statements you are considering for transversality:

Comment: 1)the direct sum of the tangent spaces of $V_{i}'s$ is the whole space  or 2) The tangent spaces have mutually trivial intersection. If you are considering the second, there is an obvious answer for k=2:I consider a very particular case but the argument can be modified in arbitrary dimension:(for k=2).Let $V_{1}$and $V_{2}$ be two transverse curve in the plane . without lose of generality we can asssume that $V_{2}$ is the y axis. so $V_{1}$ is the graph of an smooth function $y=g(x)$ after the change of coordinate x:=x, y:=y-g(x) we have $V_{1}=x$-axis  and $V_{2}$=y-axis, (standard metric)

Comment: In fact for k=2 we can do a (somehow)  simultaneous "Flow Box" argument.

Comment: @ Taghavi: transversal means tangent spaces of different components at a point are in general position, i.e. each group of them has minimum intersection. They might not generate the whole space (e.g to curves in dimension 3) or might not have mutual trivial intersection (e.g surfaces in dim 3).

Comment: @MohammadF.Tehrani Are you agree that the answer to your question is affirmative for k=2?(With a modification of my comment).Morover, is it reasonable to extend your question as follows:For arbitrary k, does there exist a change of coordinate which sends each $V_{i}$ to an affine space?(so the standard metric works, after the change of ccordinate)

Comment: @Taghavi: You special case is OK, but very easy due to your assumptions.

Comment: Just for the record, here is the precise definition of transversality: Smooth submanifolds $M_1,...,M_k$ in a smooth manifold $M$ intersect  transversally at a point $x$ if $codim_{T_xM} \cap_{i=1}^k T_x M_i= \sum_{i=1}^k codim_M(M_i)$.

Comment: @MohammadF.Tehrani Is the answer to your question obvious when all $V_{i}'s$ are curve(One dim. manifolds)?

Comment: I think  the definition of Misha in term of codimension  is not identical to Tehrani's definition. for example the three axis in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ does not satisfy in "Codimension" condition but satisfy in Tehrani's statment.@MohammadF.Tehrani could you please more clarify your question?

Comment: I was naive, Misha's definition is the rigorous one.

Comment: @MohammadF.Tehrani  So in your main question you are considering the transversality, in term of codimension? Moreover, can I ask you what is your motivation for this question?

Comment: I need to identify a neighborhood of normal bundle with a neighborhood of V in M for some construction to work.

Comment: Sounds like you need a connection, but don't really need a metric. A local construction of what you want is standard. Then I think that connections satisfying the required conditions can be averaged to give the global construction.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible in general. Here is a counterexample. Let $V_1$ be the $xy$ plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $V_2$ be the $xz$ plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $W_3$ be the surface $z=\exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x>0 $ and $z=0$ for $x\leq 0$. Then let $V_3$ be $W_3$ rotated by $45$ degrees in the $yz$-coordinates. It is easy to see that $V_1$, $V_2$, and $V_3$ are pairwise transverse. Their intersection $V$ is the interval $(-\infty,0]$ on the $x$-axis. At the origin, it is clear that not all three surfaces can be made totally geodesic with any smooth metric, because then two geodesics could be constructed so that they are different yet have the same initial velocity. I realize that $V$ is a manifold with boundary in this case. Perhaps this example could be tweaked.

Comment: A transverse set of 3 hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has only points in their triple intersection. Your example is not a transverse intersection (although every two of them are transverse).

Comment: Being transverse is a property which involves all the manifolds at the same time, transverse manifolds have minimal possible intersection on every subset.